# Make [webusercontrols] and [web-user-controls] synonyms of [webusercontrol]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[webusercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrol) : 239

[web-user-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-user-controls) : 107

[webusercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrols) : 19

Comment: Quite a lot of .NET there - but also some generic use of the term - could you provide a bit more explanation of how you feel those should be dealt with so the community can provide feedback?

Comment: @JonClements The .NET name being very generic itself (`UserControl`), there's bound to be a lot, yet other relevant tags (`ASCX`, `ASP.NET`, etc) cover those specific needs. `WebUserControl` itself is not AKAIK a .NET name.

Comment: Given the volume it's probably best as a co-ordinated cleanup/review rather than just a plain syn. - that way it might be possible to identify what's most appropriate and clean up/get attention to unanswered posts in the mean time.